# Waiting on asynchronous functions within multiple conditionals

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, callback

The meteor project I'm working on uploads files when certain conditions are satisfied. Regardless of whether or not the files are uploaded, a Meteor.call has to be made once the if statements have completed. Because of the conditionals, when I use callbacks it results in a lot of duplicate code. As it is written below, I expect the Meteor.call could be executed before the uploadFile callbacks get executed which would be a problem.

```
var data = {
  name: "..."
  //...
}
if(condition){
  uploadFile(parameters, function(error,result){
    if(err) handleError(err);
    else data.url1 = result.secure_url;
}
if(condition2){
  uploadFile(parameters, function(error,result){
    if(err) handleError(err);
    else data.url2 = result.secure_url;
}

/* This Meteor.call needs to wait until both if statements above
   have completed */

Meteor.call('insertData', data, function(error,result){
  //...
}
```

Comment: is there a chance that both the if conditions can be executed in the same case

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1g5dgrka/1/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny this works but I don't like having to make the fn() call 4 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could remove the conditionals and instead implement Javascript `Promises` they're fun and fancy plus they eliminate callback hell and provide a readable top down format:

http://jsfiddle.net/4v29u4do/1/

This fiddle shows how you could use promises to wait for async callbacks instead of conditional if statements

With promises you can `return` a new promise as the callback from a promise, and keep going and going and the callback will get passed to the new `.then` until you're done if there is any errors along the way, it skips right to the `.catch`.

```
function uploadFile(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Simulate ASYNC Call for Uploading File
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(file + ' Uploaded Successfully!');
            return resolve(file);

            // if (err) {
            //   return reject(err);
            // }
        }, 3000);
    });   
}

var data = {};

uploadFile("filename1")
.then(function(cb) {
    data.url1 = cb;
    return uploadFile("filename2");
})
.then(function(cb) {
    data.url2 = cb;
    return uploadFile("filename5"); 
})
.then(function(cb) {
    data.url3 = cb;
    console.log(data);
    //all done with callbacks
    // Meteor.call("");
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // One of the uploads failed log the err;
});
```